# Solr and spellcheck component : spellcheck.q doesn't take into consideration

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I use spellcheck component and when I request solr I have results. But if I use spellcheck.q, i haven't result.

Someone has an idea ?

Thanks

```
       <!-- The spell check component can return a list of alternative spelling
  suggestions.  -->
 <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">spellCheck</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="accuracy">0.4</str>
      <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0004</float>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

<!--<queryConverter name="queryConverter" class="solr.SpellingQueryConverter"/>-->

  <!--  Handler par défaut -->
  <requestHandler name="default" class="solr.SearchHandler" lazy="true" default="true">  
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="hl.usePhraseHighLighter">true</str>
      <str name="hl.highlightMultiTerm">true</str>
      <str name="hl.mergeContiguous">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>highlight</str>
        <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: Did you get an empty result, an error or a result with just the suggestion part missing?

Comment: @n26  
Suggestion part is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your spellcheck component to the corresponding request handler (in solr config), set *spellcheck* parameter to *true* (or *on*) and configured the correct dictionary to use (if its name different than "default")?

Comment: Yes I have added my spellcheck component to the correspondig request handler. I have suggestions if i don't use spellcheck.q param but i want to use this param

Comment: How does your solr query look like?

Comment: I don't know why but the field seems to be the cause. I change the definition of the field type and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the **spellcheck.q** parameter, then the default is to use the **q** parameter (from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#q_OR_spellcheck.q).  From that wiki:

> Essentially, if you have a spelling "ready" version in your application, then it is probably better to send spellcheck.q, otherwise, if you just want Solr to do the job, use the q parameter

The reason that it works if you change the definition of the field type is probably due to the new field type being "spelling ready".  It would help if you posted the query you are using and the relevant lines in the *schema.xml*.